# Example of a series parallel graph with toughness greater than $\frac{4}{7}$

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, hamiltonian-path

> Can anyone lead me to an example of a "more than $\frac{4}{7}$ tough series parallel graph"?

Graph toughness is defined as $T = \min \left\{\frac{|a|}{\omega{(G\backslash A)}}\right\}$ over all cut sets $A$, and $\omega(G\backslash A)$ is the number of components remain after removing the cut set.

Series parallel graphs are graphs that are created from serial or parallel join of series parallel block (which are single edges or blocks created from smaller blocks with serial join or parallel join of those blocks).

I am looking for an example of such graph which has toughness $> \frac{4}{7}$